# I can pop the first element (char) of a linked list in the main code, but I cant put that part of the code in a function

Tags: c, atmega

I m working with linked lists of chars and I need to create a function that pops the first element of the linked list, that is: delete the first node, free the space and return the char that was saved in the first node.

I created a code that does that perfectly in the main function of the program, but when I put that part of the code into a function, it stops working and I can't figure out why.

Im working with the ATmega328p and the idea is to send  the chars to the computer (Im using minicom as terminal emulator) so the function USART_Transmit_char() sends a char to the computer.

The code in the main function that works perfectly whith the pop in the main function is this one:

```
int main(void)
{
        //USART CONFIGURATION
        struct USART_configuration config_57600_8N1 = {57600, 8,1,'n'};
        USART_Init(config_57600_8N1);
        //END USART CONFIGURATION

        //CEATES THE FIRST NODE OF LINKED LIST
        node_char * string = NULL;
        string = malloc(sizeof(node_char));
        string->val = 'H';
        string->next = NULL;

        //ADD ELEMENTS TO LINKED LIST
        push(string,'O');
        push(string,'L');
        push(string,'A');

        //COMMUNICATION WITH COMPUTER
        USART_Transmit_String("I received this line: ");
        USART_Transmit_char(string->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->next->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_String(".\r\n\r\n");

        //HERE I POP THE FIRST ELEMENT
        node_char * next_node = NULL;
        char popped = string->val;
        next_node = string->next;
        free(string);
        string = next_node;
        //HERE THE FIRST ELEMENT HAS BEEN POPPED

        //COMMUNICATION WITH COMPUTER        
        USART_Transmit_String("I popped this char: ");
        USART_Transmit_char(popped);
        USART_Transmit_String(".\r\n\r\n");
        USART_Transmit_String("I am left with this: ");
        USART_Transmit_char(string->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_String(".\r\n\r\n");        
}
```

The struct of the node and the push function are :

```
typedef struct node {
        char val;
        struct node * next;
    } node_char;

void push(node_char * string, char val) {
    node_char * current = string;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_char));
    current->next->val = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}
```

The result is:

```
I recived this line: HOLA.

I popped this char: H.

I am left whit this: OLA.
```

The problem comes when I change the part of the code that pops the craracter for a function defined appart that has the exact same code.

The new main code is:

```
int main(void)
{
        //USART CONFIGURATION
        struct USART_configuration config_57600_8N1 = {57600, 8,1,'n'};
        USART_Init(config_57600_8N1);
        //END USART CONFIGURATION

        //CEATES THE FIRST NODE OF LINKED LIST
        node_char * string = NULL;
        string = malloc(sizeof(node_char));
        string->val = 'H';
        string->next = NULL;

        //ADD ELEMENTS TO LINKED LIST
        push(string,'O');
        push(string,'L');
        push(string,'A');

        //COMMUNICATION WITH COMPUTER
        USART_Transmit_String("I received this line: ");
        USART_Transmit_char(string->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->next->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_String(".\r\n\r\n");

        //HERE I POP THE FIRST ELEMENT

        char popped = pop(string);

        //HERE THE FIRST ELEMENT HAS BEEN POPPED

        //COMMUNICATION WITH COMPUTER
        USART_Transmit_String("I popped this char: ");
        USART_Transmit_char(popped);
        USART_Transmit_String(".\r\n\r\n");
        USART_Transmit_String("I am left with this: ");
        USART_Transmit_char(string->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_char(string->next->next->val);
        USART_Transmit_String(".\r\n\r\n");        
}
```

The function pop is defined:

```
char pop(node_char * string) {
    node_char * next_node = NULL;
    char popped = string->val;
    next_node = string->next;
    free(string);
    string = next_node;
    return popped;
}
```

The result is:

```
I recived this line: HOLA.

I popped this char: H.

I am left whit this: 
                      .
```

(Note that the (.) is printed in the next line)

I cant figure out why this doesn't work when its te same code just defined in a function.

Does anyone have an Idea why this is happening? I've tried a lot of different ways for solving the problem, with diferent results but never the desired result.

Comment: This assignment `string = next_node;` does *not* survive the return of the `pop` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `pop()`  you assign the `local` parameter `string`:

```
string = next_node;
```

But here `string` is a local variable and not associated with `string` in `main()` - it is simply a copy of the *value* of `string` in `main()` - or was until you modified it.

You need an additional level of indirection, so that you are passing a pointer to the `string` object from `main()`:

```
char pop(node_char** string) 
{
    node_char* next_node = NULL;
    char popped = (*string)->val;
    next_node = (*string)->next;
    free(*string);
    *string = next_node ;

    return popped;
}
```

Then call:

```
char popped = pop( &string ) ;
```